# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -Centos 7.1

Tags: zabbix

Logs:

> 20088:20180822:152017.613 cannot send list of active checks to "127.0.0.1": host [Zabbix server] not monitored
>
> 20100:20180822:152202.973 [Z3005] query failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) [select escalationid,actionid,triggerid,eventid,r_eventid,nextcheck,esc_step,status,itemid from escalations where triggerid is not null order by actionid,triggerid,itemid,escalationid]
>
> 20100:20180822:152202.973 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbixdb' failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
> 20100:20180822:152202.973 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds

Comment: start mysqld service and test the connection to mysql with command "mysql -u root -p"

Answer (score 0):

In mysql set grant zbbixdb to to zabbixuser for IP 127.0.0.1 and try again

`grant all privileges on zabbixdb.* to 'zabbixuser'@'127.0.0.1';`

Comment: The issue described is a failed connection to the local socket, not an authentication or permission error.

Answer (score 0):

Grant all privileges to the Zabbix user that you have defined in your zabbix agent configuration file and grant him privileges over the database that you have specified on the same conf. file.

grant all privileges on ZabbixDBName.* to 'ZabbixUserUsed'@'127.0.0.1';

use this query in mysql for the same.